# How can I capture and display multiple images in android

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I need to capture multiple images and display on the screen

[image]

I am able to take a single image and show on image view but I do not know how to display multiple images.

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                } 
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    } 
}
```